# How to get the puts output to read actual numbers instead of (x,y)

Tags: ruby

So my written program works, but when I get the output it says, point x,y lies at "insert end". What do I need to change to get the "x,y" to give the digits that are inputted?

```
puts "Enter the x and y coordinate points:"
x = gets.chomp.to_f
y = gets.chomp.to_f

if x > 0 and y > 0
  puts "point #{"x,y"} lies in the First quadrant"
elsif x < 0 and y > 0
  puts "point #{"x,y"} lies in the Second quadrant"
elsif x < 0 and y < 0
  puts "point #{"x,y"} lies in the Third quadrant"
elsif x > 0 and y < 0
  puts "point #{"x,y"} lies in the Fourth quadrant"
elsif x == 0 and y > 0
  puts "point #{"x,y"} lies at the positive y axis"
elsif x == 0 and y < 0
  puts "point #{"x,y"} lies at the negative y axis"
elsif y == 0 and x < 0
  puts "point #{"x,y"} lies at the negative x axis"
elsif y == 0 and x > 0
  puts "point #{"x,y"} lies at the positive x axis"
else
  puts "point #{"x,y"} lies at the origin"
end
```

Comment: BTW you don't need `chomp` in `gets.chomp.to_f`

Comment: Great username based on a awesome book :)

Comment: @nPn Thanks! It's truly an awesome series by an awesome author.

Answer (score 2):

Use two `#{}` constructs (one for each variable) to interpolate the two variables like this:

```rb
puts "point #{x},#{y} lies in the first quadrant"
```

`#{"x,y"}` simply inserts the string "x,y" into the string, which isn't what you want.

Interpolating both variables into the string with a single `#{}` is possible, but it is a bit more verbose because you have to call `to_s` twice since `x` and `y` are floats. They can't be concatenated as-is with `','` as Ruby will try to convert the string to a float and then complain that it can't.

```rb
puts "point #{x.to_s + ',' + y.to_s} lies in the first quadrant"
```

Comment: That fixed the number problem. Why when the input comes out does it give me 3.0,3.0 instead of 3,3?

Comment: Because `x` and `y` are floats. `String#to_f` converts the string to a floating point number. If you want integers use `to_i`.

Comment: @Speak3r4theDead:  Be careful, depending on the specifics of your project, integers may be a bad idea.  Both ```0.9, 0.9``` and ```-0.9, -0.9```would result in ```"point 0,0 lies at the origin"```.  In addition, you would have a similar problem where any non-zero values between -1 and 1 would result in reporting along a specific axis when they really belong in a quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out `"#{value}"` interpolates value and your value is the literal "x,y" which is why you get the result you do.
If you want more control of how the values are formatted you can do something like this:

```
formatted_point = "point %.1f, %.1f" % [x,y]
```

and then use it like this.

```
puts "#{formatted_point} lies in the First quadrant"
```

You can find all the details on string formatting [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-format)